# How to fetch two values as string from JSON array

Tags: android

I have `JSONArray` returning two values

```
Phone Array : [{"type":"H","value":"9845313133"},{"type":"H","value":"9987546132"}]
```

How can I get both values in separate string something like

```
String A = "9845313133"
String B = "9987546132"
```

Below is what I will be iterating

```
JSONArray phoneArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("phone");
```

Current code :

```
JSONObject cit = phoneArray.getJSONObject(0);
String phoneNumbers = "";
for (int count=1; count <= phoneArray.length(); count++) {
    if (phoneNumbers.length() == 0)
        phoneNumbers += phoneArray.getJSONObject(count-1).getString("value");
    else
        phoneNumbers += ", " + phoneArray.getJSONObject(count-1).getString("value");
}
```

Comment: Just parse your JSON into POJO object .

Comment: How are you getting the data?

Comment: I have problem because both values has one key "value", in that case how do I identify both as separate string

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
            String[] phoneNumbers = new String[phoneArray.length()];
            for (int count=0; count <= phoneArray.length(); count++)

            {
               JSONObject cit = phoneArray.getJSONObject(count);

               phoneNumbers[count] =  cit.getString("value");

        }
```

at the end , you will have all phone numbers in phoneNumbers array.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have already parsed the data into `phoneNumbers` variable separated by a comma, then you can simply so a `split` on it to get the phone numbers.

```
String[] numbers = phoneNumbers.split(", ");
```

You can access each phone number as `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]` and so on.

Note : Check the bounds before accessing the data as follows, else you will run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
if(numbers.length > 0){
    String A = numbers[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `ArrayList` to store multiple `String` values.

**2.** Parse `"value"` one by one and store it into `ArrayList`

**Here is the working code:**

```
try {

    // RESPONSE = [{"type":"H","value":"9845313133"},{"type":"H","value":"9987546132"}]
    JSONArray phoneArray = RESPONSE;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int count = 0; count < phoneArray.length(); count++)
    {
        JSONObject object = phoneArray.getJSONObject(count);
        String phoneNumber = object.getString("value");

        // Add phoneNumber to list
        list.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        Log.d("OUTPUT", "Value: " + list.get(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/OUTPUT: Value: 9845313133
D/OUTPUT: Value: 9987546132
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class for JSONObjects retrieved from JSONArray i.e., "phone Array".

Below is the code for POJO class `Example`:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
```

Then to get values in POJO class use `Gson` in the following manner.

```
    JSONArray phoneArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("phone");
    final ArrayList<Example> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<phoneArray.length();i++){
      Gson gson = new Gson();
    arrList.add(gson.fromJson(phoneArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Example.class));
    }
```

You can get value of all phone numbers using `geValue()` method of `Example` class.